# Select a value out of two in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing like this:

```
var bound = 0;
if(myVar < minY) bound = minY;
else bound = maxY;
```

to select the value `minY` or `maxY` depending on the condition `(myVar < minY)`. What's the cleanest, shortest way to do it properly in JavaScript?

Comment: what is B.y?  .................

Comment: sorry, I restated the question properly

Comment: the code you have seems perfectly fine then

Comment: ternary operator? more readable?

Comment: if you want to split hairs

Comment: ahah ok.. fair enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're looking for [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var bound = myVar < minY ? minY : maxY;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you are trying to do. Seems like you are trying to put this logic into some kind of loop, but there is a better way:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 0];
arr.min() // 0
arr.max() // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`to select the minimum value between minY and maxY` ...

easy... will be `minY`.

Comment: sorry, I restated the question properly

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is the shortest one but in javascript if you are getting values from element_id like `$('#element').val()` They will return only `string` not `number`.

So better use `parseInt(value)` before comparing value.

```
var bound = parseInt(myVar) < parseInt(minY) ? minY : maxY;
```